# Pixel size is bigger on Firefox and IE than in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an issue setting the font size which I'm not sure if its the reason of the difference between the pixel size between browsers. 
I have set the following meta tag on my index.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

And in the html element CSS i have set:

```
 font-size: 16px !important;
```

In the rest of the element's CSS I'm setting the font-size with rem (relative to html size which is 16px)

Yet I still have a massive difference of sizes on FF and IE11 - Zoom in all browsers is set to 100%, text size to medium in IE 11.

It doesn't only look like the font is the issue, every element on the page is MASSIVE on these browsers! Only Chrome displays the site as it should.

Anyone knows the issue? I'm going crazy with this one. Thanks in advance!

Here some pictures so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image][image]

Comment: Your second image has a magnifying glass in the URL bar, indicating you are not at 100% zoom.

Comment: Indeed...! I missed that...! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Basically pixels are static so the font should be same anywhere.

I have noticed one thing in the second Screenshot that zoom-out symbol at the top right side of the address bar that means mistakenly you have zoom-out the page. Click on that symbol then make it 100% check the screenshot below for reference.

[image]

I have Highlighted the icon in yellow colour similarly you will find it in your browser click on it and make it 100%. Hopes this solve your problem